# Which monkey species features two distinct male phenotypes?

Tags: reproduction, sociality, fitness

I remember coming across a popular science article years ago about a monkey species which featured two male genotypes: the first were good looking males who acquired social status (as alphas or betas) within the group and could thus achieve reproductive succes. The alternative (less frequent) phenotype achieved similar fitness by adopting an outgroup (omega) lurking rapist kind of reproductive strategy.

Does anybody know which species and whose observervations I could be referring to? I'm curious to find out if this was a valid observation and if any further research has been done on this phenomenon.

Comment: Related behaviour in lizards: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_side-blotched_lizard

Comment: Search term 'alternative reproductive strategy' for lots of related behaviors in various organisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Patas monkeys](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02382664) exhibit "sneak mating" where a male other than the resident male sires offspring. Resident males do sire more offspring than sneaker males, but both strategies do co-occur. I'm pretty sure there are other species that have a similar mating strategy as well.

Comment: Although I'm pretty sure that this is not the species I was looking for, this behaviour resembles the description in my question closely enough, so I'm accepting your answer.